# Event launched many times with Jquery

Tags: jquery, events, scroll, google-analytics

The idea is to launch an event when the user see in his browser an specific image of my page. To do this, I have use this code:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    var $controlables = $('.other-service');
    var doScroll = function() {
            var offset = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            if ($controlables.size() == 0) {
                $(window).off('scroll', doScroll);
            }

            $controlables.each(function(i) {
            var $controlable = $(this);
            if (($controlable.offset().top + $controlable.height() - 20) < offset) {
                ga('send', 'event', 'providers', 'services', 'scroll');
                return false;
            }
        });
    };

    $(window).on('scroll', doScroll);
    $(window).trigger('scroll');

});
</script>
```

The problem is that the event is launched 10 or 20 times at once. How can I fix this?

Comment: The issue is because the `scroll` event fires once for every single pixel that the window scrolls. You need to either debounce the event or set a flag to state that that element has already been processed.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. How can I set a flag or how can I do that you said?